# CKEditor 5 - How to set the editor's height programmatically from the TypeScript, NOT from CSS

Tags: angular, ckeditor5

I am using CKEditor 5 in an Angular 8 project. I know I can set editor's editor's height through stylesheet using

```
:host ::ng-deep .ck-editor__editable {
    min-height: 500px;
}
```

This approach works.

**But I cannot use this** as I cannot know the min-height should be 500px before hand. The desired height will be calculated in the **TypeScript**. Hence I need to know how to set it from there.

I have tried setting the height using **querySelector**. Like-

`selector.style.minHeight = calculatedHeight`

It works initially but the problem is when the editor is focused/blurred, the event functions are called which **resets the height to the height of total content inside it.

Now, I can handle these event to readjust the height again like the following -

```
<ckeditor [editor]="Editor" (ready)="onReady($event)" (focus)="readjustHeight()" (blur)="readjustHeight()" data="<p>Hello, world!</p>"></ckeditor>
```

Now focusing retains the provided height. But when clicked else where which triggers blur event, the height readjusts but some other follow up event resets it again. I don't know which event is fired after blur. Also, this is not a good solution either.

**TL;DR:**
The `min-height` for the editor I want to set is dynamic and is calculated in the TypeScript. So I cannot use CSS and need set the height from TypeSript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question as it may come in handy for other. Got the answer from the CKEditor team on Github.

To adjust the height of the editable element it will look like this:

```
editor.editing.view.change( writer => {
    writer.setStyle( 'height', '200px', editor.editing.view.document.getRoot() );
} );
```

This works with all types of editors.

Comment: just in case anyone else is brand new to ck editor, and you're using angular, you put in this function inside the (ready) event of the tag like this:  
      
`<ckeditor [config]="config" [editor]="Editor" data="" [formControl]="myForm.controls['message']" (ready)="onReady($event)" ></ckeditor>`

Comment: Nice! This is the answer I am looking for!!!

Answer (score 2):

For those who are looking for react `config={{ height: 400 }}`

Answer (score 0):

Does `ckeditor` component is a direct child of host component? If yes, then

```
:host ckeditor ::ng-deep .ck-editor__editable {
    min-height: 500px;
}
```

In order to pass custom config to ckeditor component you can use [config input](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_angular.html#config). In order to set the height there is [config prop](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-height)

Comment: Using CSS works, but i mentioned it clearly that I have to do it from the TypeScript. My `min-height` is **not predefined** like 500px you mentioned here. The height needs to be calculated in the typescript and then set.

Comment: Changed the answer. There is config input param in the component to set it up

Comment: That's CKEditor4 and I am using **CKEditor5**. Anyways, I have found my answer from the CKEditor team.